# Restricting to values of 01 through 10 in XSD?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to understand the use of patterns in XSD.
Hows does '+' in a pattern for a restriction work in XSD?

After some research, I found out that I can use restrictions with patterns. I do understand that the "+" means 1 or more. But will it also apply in this case?

```
<xsd:simpleType name="typeNumber">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:ID">
            <xsd:pattern value="nr[0-9]+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

Will, for example, the value `nr12345` be valid?
Furthermore, I would like to know how it would be possible to make the acceptable value between `nr01` and `nr10`.

Comment: Should be possible to apply the XSD against some XML and observe the results.. this should be used to be able to form a more complete base question/hypothesis.

Comment: There are also resources on what the regular expressions are supported by patterns are allowed for XML, eg. https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html , http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/rnc/xsd-regex.html , http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html (searched for "xml pattern regex")

Comment: Matching: `nr01..nr10` is the same as matching `nr01..nr09` *or* `nr10`. Should be able to use that in conjunction with the current pattern and links above. The alternation (`|`, aka "either or") operator will be useful.

Comment: Frankly, if only ten values are allowed, I would be inclined to use an enumeration rather than a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This XSD type,

```
<xsd:simpleType name="typeNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:ID">
        <xsd:pattern value="nr0[1-9]"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="nr10"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

will allow `nr01` through `nr09` and `nr10`, as requested, without needing `+`, which, yes, does mean 1 or more occurences.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
<xsd:simpleType name="typeNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:ID">
        <xsd:pattern value="nr(0?[1-9]|10)"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

**Details**

The regex will match an entire string that matches

- `nr` - `nr` at the start of the string
- `(0?[1-9]|10)` - an optional `0` followed with a non-zero digit (see `0?[1-9]` alternative) or (`|`) `10` value.